# online radio streaming app not running what is the mistake?

Tags: java, xml

I cant run the app. but its showing no errors on compile, and pro-grammatically it appears about right , stucked just need help... i've tried both android studio and eclipse ... and tried to solve java codes but not working at all...
//Here is the java code

```
package com.radio.radio_hola;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.app.Activity;
import java.io.IOException;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

@SuppressWarnings({ "deprecation", "unused" })
public class myMain extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private ProgressBar playSeekBar;

    private Button buttonPlay;

    private Button buttonStopPlay;

    private MediaPlayer player;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initializeUIElements();

        initializeMediaPlayer();
    }

    private void initializeUIElements() {

        playSeekBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        playSeekBar.setMax(100);
        playSeekBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        buttonPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPlay);
        buttonPlay.setOnClickListener(this);

        buttonStopPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStopPlay);
        buttonStopPlay.setEnabled(false);
        buttonStopPlay.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == buttonPlay) {
            startPlaying();
        } else if (v == buttonStopPlay) {
            stopPlaying();
        }
    }

    private void startPlaying() {
        buttonStopPlay.setEnabled(true);
        buttonPlay.setEnabled(false);

        playSeekBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        player.prepareAsync();

        player.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                player.start();
            }
        });

    }

    private void stopPlaying() {
        if (player.isPlaying()) {
            player.stop();
            player.release();
            initializeMediaPlayer();
        }

        buttonPlay.setEnabled(true);
        buttonStopPlay.setEnabled(false);
        playSeekBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    private void initializeMediaPlayer() {
        player = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            player.setDataSource("http://usa8-vn.mixstream.net:8138");
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        player.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new OnBufferingUpdateListener() {

            public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
                playSeekBar.setSecondaryProgress(percent);
                Log.i("Buffering", "" + percent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (player.isPlaying()) {
            player.stop();
        }
    }
}



// Main Activity starts from here

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.radio.radio_megh.MainActivity" >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Space
            android:id="@+id/space1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="93dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonPlay"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/play" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonStopPlay"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttonPlay"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="@string/stop"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/buttonPlay"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/buttonPlay"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttonStopPlay"
            android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
            tools:ignore="RtlCompat,RtlHardcoded" />

        <MediaController
            android:id="@+id/player"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="26dp" >
        </MediaController>

    </RelativeLayout>

//download link of my project: drive.google.com/file/d/0BxZZZBIvPIvmVzhhc0xhYTVINnc/view?usp=sharing
```

Comment: Not running is a big statement. Does it start to run and crash? What are you seeing and expect to see?

Comment: Also, please try to cut your code down to a minimum, it's hard to use an example this big to troubleshoot.

Comment: it has two parts showing @Jason D, one is .java and other .xml

Comment: it notifies "unfortunately, 'app' has stopped. " at start, @Shawn